# Extra div getting added in sightly html markup in if-else condition

Tags: html, aem, templating, sightly

An extra div gets added in sightly if else html markup; when the the second block is not executed. There are three conditions based on checkbox in author dialog. When the second checkbox is not checked; then first and third condition are true and second condition is false; so the second sightly block should not get executed. But it adds an extra div in the markup ; so that the div with class  "container tabs-container" gets closed in between.

-- please find below the sightly markup

```
<sly data-sly-test.condition1="${properties.checkbox1}">
<sly data-sly-test.condition2="${properties.checkbox2}">
<sly data-sly-test.condition3="${properties.checkbox3}">

<div class="tabs-body">
            <div class="container tabs-container">

                <!--/* First condition */-->
                <sly data-sly-test="${condition1}">
                    <div class="tabs-body-item" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id1">

                    </div>
                </sly>                

                <!--/* Second condition */-->
                <sly data-sly-test="${condition2}">
                    <sly data-sly-test="${condition1}">
                    <div class="tabs-body-item" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id2">
                    </sly>
                    <sly data-sly-test="${!condition1}">
                    <div class="tabs-body-item is-active" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id2">
                    </sly>
                    </div>
                </sly>

                <!--/* Third condition */-->
                <sly data-sly-test="${condition3}">
                    <sly data-sly-test.condition2andcondition1false="${!condition2 && !condition1}">
                        <div class="tabs-body-item is-active" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id3">
                    </sly>
                    <sly data-sly-test="${!condition2andcondition1false}">
                        <div class="tabs-body-item" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id3">
                    </sly>
                    </div>
                </sly>


            </div> 
        </div>
```

The markup rendered is --

```
<div class="tabs-body">
            <div class="container tabs-container">


                    <div class="tabs-body-item" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id1">

                    </div>


                </div><!--extra div-->





                        <div class="tabs-body-item" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id3">

                    </div>


            </div> 
        </div>
```

The extra div has been mentioned with  comment. I have spent much time on it but can't figure out from where the extra div is getting added. Could you sightly experts please help me out with this?

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably due to invalid nesting of the tags. Do not try to convert JSTL code as is to HTL.

```
<div class="tabs-body">
    <div class="container tabs-container">

        <!--/* First condition */-->
        <div class="tabs-body-item" data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id1" 
            data-sly-test.condition1="${properties.checkbox1}">

        </div>

        <!--/* Second condition */-->
        <div class="tabs-body-item ${ condition1 ? '' : 'is-active' }" 
            data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id2" 
            data-sly-test.condition2="${properties.checkbox2}">

        </div>

        <!--/* Third condition */-->
        <div class="tabs-body-item ${condition1 && condition2 ? 'is-active' : ''}" 
            data-tab-content-id="data-tab-content-id3" 
            data-sly-test="${properties.checkbox3}">

        </div>

    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Good one @rakhi4110 , this worked; however; still don't understand how the extra div was getting added. Did sightly by itself added the extra div?

Comment: Nope. Sightly wouldn't add an extra div. However, when the tags are not nested properly, the `data-sly-test` condition doesn't apply to the entire section as expected. In your case, when your `condition2` is false, it has to skip the entire second section, however due to improper nesting of tags, the `</div>` was being left out of the section.